# calldata keyword as parameter in solidity v0.5.0 function?

Tags: solidity, calldata, modifiers

What purpose does the "calldata" serve in this parameter _owners? Is it a new keyword?

```
  function setup(address[] calldata _owners, uint256 _threshold, address to, bytes calldata data)
```

Taken from [Gnosis Safe Contract - GnosisSafe.sol](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/development/contracts/GnosisSafe.sol#L49)

Comment: See https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/050-breaking-changes.html#explicitness-requirements. You now have to explicitly state the location of structs, arrays, and mappings when they're parameters.

Answer (score 28):

As per the Solidity version 0.5.0 breaking changes [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html#explicitness-requirements) :

> Explicit data location for all variables of struct, array or mapping
> types is now mandatory. This is also applied to function parameters
> and return variables.

So currently, reference types comprise structs, arrays and mappings. If you use a reference type, you always have to explicitly provide the data area where the type is stored:

- **`memory`** (whose lifetime is limited to a function call)
- **`storage`** (the location where the state variables are stored)
- **[`calldata`](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/types.html?highlight=data%20location#data-location)** (special data location that contains the function arguments,
  only available for external function call parameters).

So here in the shared contract, data location has been mentioned which is `calldata`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`calldata` is immutable and temporary data location. if you are not going to modify the function argument use `calldata` to save gas. otherwise use `memory` keyword.